# Cron [ERROR] No AWS credentials found - check your credentials

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, cron

I scheduled a cron job for graffiti-monkey:

```
15 0  * * * /home/ubuntu/scripts/graffiti_monkey.sh
```

but its not executing and log says

```
[ERROR] No AWS credentials found - check your credentials
```

How can I give aws crendentials to the `.sh` file so that cron will execute it?

Comment: Depends on what your script is doing.  Please elaborate.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/graffiti-monkey --region ap-southeast-1

Comment: what are the permissions for `graffiti_monkey.sh`?

Comment: the script is running but displays aws credentials error

Comment: Most probably, your AWS credentials are in some configuration file whihch is `sourced`. So if you run the script manually, it will work but it will fail via cron because cron cannot read the shell level variables. So `source` your credentials in your cron. e.g. `15 0  * * * source ~/.bashrc && /home/ubuntu/scripts/graffiti_monkey.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Command Line Interface documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) describes a few ways to store credentials.

Try executing `aws configure` in your terminal (as the user running the cron):

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the permission your `graffiti_monkey.sh` file is having change it to execute from others that is 555 than run it also check this info I found.

**cron permissions**

The following two files play an important role:

•   `/etc/cron.allow` - If this file exists, it must contain your username for you to use cron jobs.

•   `/etc/cron.deny` - If the cron.allow file does not exist but the `/etc/cron.deny`file does exist then, to use cron jobs, you must not be listed in the `/etc/cron.deny` file.
Note that if neither of these files exist then, depending on site-dependent configuration parameters, either only the super user can use cron jobs, or all users can use cron jobs.